# Ajax BeginForm - OnFailure return error message

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, error-handling

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to call my application to run some code. On error, I would like to return the custom error message which I will create.

However I haven't been able to do it this far. This is what I have:

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(UserViewModel model) {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return Json(new { error = "Broken" });
        }
```

Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "User", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "window.location.reload();", OnFailure = "AjaxFailed(error);" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", @id = "EditForm" })) {
}
```

Javascript:

```
function AjaxFailed(error) {
    debugger
    $(".ErrorBox").prop('hidden', false);
    $('.ModalErrorText').text("An error occured, please review the data and try again.");
}
```

I would've thought that the BeginForm would have caught the error which I returned and passed it through to the Javascript, but it doesn't. Can anyone help me return the error message to me Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Any luck on figuring out the correct way of doing this without handling the failure inside the onSuccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used only onSuccess and removed `StatusCode` and `onFailure`. Hope it also works!

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(UserViewModel model) {
        if(success)
            return Json(new { votes = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(new { error = "Broken" });
}
```

**Script**

```
function onSuccess(result) {
    if (result.error) {
          alert(result.error); //do error
    } 
    else {
         alert(result.votes); //do success 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought about doing this but I just feel like its a bit deceitful. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear it works! btw can you choose as right answer? :)

Comment: I chose your answer as the answer because at the time it was correct. But I think the correct way of doing it is to return an ActionResult as you can return a JsonResult via an action result. To return error you need to set the status code to one that your browser recognises as a failure